# Display image stored in internal storage in an ImageView ? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, uri, android-imageview, android-file

I first store an image in internal storage this way:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("myimage.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

And then I display it in an `ImageView` this way:

```
File filepath = context.getFileStreamPath("myimage.png");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(filepath.toString());
myImageView.setImageUri(uri);
```

But the image never appears in the `ImageView`. I cannot use `setImageBitmap()` here due to some constraints. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

Instead of `context.getFileStreamPath("myimage.png");` you can try `Uri uri = Uri.parse(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/myimage.png");`

Comment: Have you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in the manifest?

How is the bitmap declared?

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not required as I am using internal storage for read/write operations. For bitmap, I first open the Gallery, then when an image is selected, I use BitmapFactory.decodeFile() on it. This part works fine. The problem is in the ImageView part.

Comment: Ok, then try `filepath.getPath();` instead of `filepath.toString()`

Answer (score -1):

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), getFileStreamPath("myimage.png").getAbsolutePath());

imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

or

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFileStreamPath("myimage.png").getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/myimage.png");